# What does the `varName {` syntax mean in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am totally new to Groovy, coming from a Java background. I am trying to learn it because it's used by the "Job DSL Plugin" in Jenkins. I'm trying to understand the example code snippet posted on the plugin's homepage as a first step.

Here's a snippet of their code for reference:

```
branches.each {
    def branchName = it.name
    job {
        name "${project}-${branchName}".replaceAll('/','-')
        scm {
            git("git://github.com/${project}.git", branchName)
        }
        steps {
            maven("test -Dproject.name=${project}/${branchName}")
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to understand is what `job {` means above. I know it's going to be a Groovy `Closure` but I don't understand the syntax. All the Groovy tutorials I have read have used a syntax like `def job = {...}` (defining a closure) or `job(...)` (calling a closure). Is this a shorthand for one of those? How about the other instances like `scm {` and `steps {` - are they working in a similar way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you define a method like so:

```
def job(Closure c) {
    println c()
}
```

Then in Groovy, you can call:

```
job({
    "Hello World"
})
```

And Groovy's parser lets you omit the parentheses, so that can just become:

```
job {
    "Hello World"
}
```

Another form you may see follows the rule that if a CLosure is the last parameter of a method, it can be called outside of the parentheses, ie:

```
def job(String who, Closure c) {
    println c(who)
}

job("World") { who ->
    "Hello $who"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @tim_yates mentioned, the low-level syntax is a `closure` but at a higher level this fwould be considered a `builder` - you can find good examples in [MarkupBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html) and [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html).

I don't know anything about the plugin you are using and whether the `job`, `scm`, `steps`, etc. are predefined, because with a `builder` you can have predefined method names or dynamic method names with the help of the `methodMissing` method.

Just a guess, but possibly within the plugin's internal implementation, there is a method named `job` that instantiates an object and returns it based on the passed in `closure`.

```
BranchBuilder {
    Branch branch

    Branch job(Closure passedInClosure) {
        branch = new Branch()
        passedInClosure()
        return branch
    }

    ...
}
```

This `passedInClosure` would contain `name`, `scm`, `steps` closures which depending on the implementation would probably exist in the `BranchBuilder`:

```
void name(String branchName) {
    branch.name = branchName
}

void scm(Closure passedInClosure) {
    // the passedInClosure at this point contains the git closure which maybe isn't explicity defined
    passedInClosure()
}
```

To give an example of how the `methodMissing` could work in this situation (also in `BranchBuilder`):

```
def methodMissing(String name, arguments) {
    if(name == 'git') {
        branch.scms << new SourceControl(system: 'Git', url: arguments[0], branchName: arguments[1])
    } else if (name == 'svn') {
        branch.scms << new SourceControl(system: 'Subversion', url: arguments[0], branchName: arguments[1])
    }
}
```

The [Groovy Goodness site](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/11/groovy-goodness-create-simple-builders.html) does a better job than I can in explaining this but hopefully I've broken it down somewhat.